# LINQ Left Outer Join with Greater Than and Less Than Date Conditions

Tags: linq, conditional-statements, left-join

I've been struggling with this for a while and can't find the syntax for a LINQ outer join that has multiple conditions based on date. I've been looking into the GroupJoin syntax, but that only let's you compare one field value (normally IDs).

I would like to test if the parent table has a date (e.g. "UpdateDate") that falls within multiple values defined in the child table (e.g. "StartDate" and "EndDate"). If the parent date fits the condition, pull a column or two from the child table. If not, those columns from the child table should be null (classic left join stuff).

I don't think query syntax will work because it only recognizes equijoins.

**Is there a way to do this in LINQ using Lambda syntax?** I've been trying to use some combination of "SelectMany" and "DefaultIfEmpty" but keep getting stuck trying to define the join.

Comment: Could you add some sample data (3 - 10 entities) and which entities should come out by some given constraints?

Comment: Regarding sample data, for simplicity, just imagine a parent table with an ID, Desc and UpdateDate, and a child (maybe "secondary" table would be a better description) with StartDate, EndDate and WeekNumber columns. There is no matching column between the two tables. I hope this helps ...

Comment: Nope. Please add some **code** to your question. Write down a simple sample class (e.g. `public class MyEntity { public int Id {get; set;} }` or multiple to show relationship) and some code that creates a list (or multiple for relationship) with a few entities of them. Then write down which constrains you like to set in your query and which entities of the above should come out. If you give this, I could easily copy this code and work on your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this in linq:

```
var q = from a in TableA
        from b in TableB.where(x => a.Date > x.StartDate && a.Date < x.EndDate).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select {...}
```

Comment: Aha, yeh, the `into g` is not useful in this case since it isn't a group join. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `ResultSelector` of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupJoin__4_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1____3___) to select what you want:

```
var result = dbContext.Parents.GroupJoin(dbContext.Children,

    // outer and inner key Selectors:
    parent => parent.Id,       // from every parent take the primary key
    child => child.ParentId,   // from every child take the foreign key to parent

    // ResultSelector: take the parent and all his children to make one new object
    (parent, children) => new
    {
        // Select only the Parent properties you actually plan to use:
        Id = parent.Id,
        Name = parent.Name,
        ...

        Children = children.Select(child => new
        {
            // select only Child properties you plan to use:
            Id = child.Id,
            // No need: you know the value: ParentId = child.ParentId,
            ...
```

"If the parent date fits the condition, pull a column or two from the child table, otherwise those columns from the child table should be null "

```
            SpecialColumnA = (parent.BirthDay.Year < 2000) ?? child.BirthDay : null,
            SpecialColumnB = (parent.Name == "Kennedy" ?? child.Name : null,
    });
```

If the conditions are the same for a  lot of columns, consider to check this only once:

```
        SpecialColumns = (parent.Birthday.Year >= 2000) ? null :
            // else fill the special columns:
            new
            {
                Name = child.Name,
                SomeWeirdProperty = parent.Id + child.Id,
                ...
            },
    });
```

Comment: Harold, there is no matching primary/foreign key column between the two tables. I didn't design the DB .... Would your solution still apply in this case?

Comment: A GroupJoin is a SQL Left Outer Join followed by a GroupBy. If your key selectors select properties that can be used to do a join, then I guess it works. On the other hand: why don't you try it in a dummy project with `List<Parent>` and `List<Child>`?

Comment: I had been trying in a dummy project, but couldn't get it to work, which is why I posted here.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it with two Lists where I GroupJoined Parents and  on Children on LastName, to get "Parents with their Children". And it worked.